# How to correctly view htm files containing Kanji in the web browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internationalization, japanese

I am trying to read parallel English-Japanese texts. When I open them in **Firefox** or **Chromium**, I just see gibberish like:

[image]

But when I view the markup in **Kate**, I see the characters displayed correctly. With **gedit** I see gibberish, but a different kind of gibberish than with a browser.

The Kate editor shows that the encoding is **Shift_jis**, but when I configure this as the fallback encoding nothing happens.

Please could you explain this behavior and help me correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the metadata of the html files. After reading [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), I realized that all I need to do was change the header:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

to

```
<HTML><HEAD><META encoding=utf-8 charset=shift-jis 
             NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```